# makeindex is skipping some entries

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

When checking the PDF file of the document I'm currently working on, I've noticed that some of the Chapters and Parts are missing in the side-bar index. I've been using imakeidx as shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeindex 
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\begin{document}
    \part{Part One}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    \chapter{Third Chapter}
    \chapter{Chapter 4}
    \chapter{Chapter 5}
    \chapter{Next Chapter}
    \chapter{Chapter after Next Chapter}
    \chapter{Yet another chapter}
    \chapter{Final Chapter for Part One}
    \chapter{Ok, This is Really the Final Chapter for this Part}
    \part{Part Two}
    \part{Part Three}
\end{document}
```

This minimal working example works out just fine for me. However, for example, in the original document Parts 2 to 6 and Chapters 2 to 6 are missing. I have no idea what could be causing this issue or how I could possibly fix it.

Comment: makeindex sorts alphabetic index of words marked with `\index` and you have none, I think you mean the pdf bookmarks (which are made by hyperref)  The posted code has no `\part` and does not have 6 chapters so there is no way it can be an example of the problem that you describe, so it isn't really possible to help with the information provided

Comment: Yeah, pdf bookmarks I mean, didn't know it's called that. I didn't include that many Parts and Chapters in the minimal working example.. it's fixed now and the posted version is still working just fine. All Chapters and Parts are there in the PDF file generated by this minimal working example. The issues start with the real document.

Comment: Is there something I could have done wrong along the way somewhere in the document to prevent pdf bookmarks from working correctly?

Comment: There really is no point in posting an example if it is not an example of the problem you are asking about. We know what a latex document looks like showing another one does not help. You can _always_ make an example of the problem. Start from a copy of your document. Delete all the text just leaving the headings (or maybe leave a line of `hello world` text in each section. Check the problem still occurs. Delete any package from the preamble you can delete while still showing the problem. Post the resulting document.  If you delete something and the problem goes, you solved the issue yourself.

Comment: have you run latex enough times? After an edit you need to run latex at least twice more for the tables of contents and bookmarks to stabilise

Comment: Yeah, I have run it dozen's of times.

Comment: then you need to post an example

Comment: Do the missing chapters appear in \tableofcontents?

Comment: Yes, the tableofcontents is working perfectly.